# Contact individual Summary Print page Image not showing

Tags: templates

When in the contact individual summary page i have an image that i upload and it shows.  When i go to the action button and use print summary. On the print page the image does not show up.

I tried adding this to /sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Taskprint.tpl

```
{if !empty($imageURL)}
            <div id="crm-contact-thumbnail">
{/if}
```

it does not load the image. does anyone know how to make the image load in the print summary page ?

I am using drupal and civicrm  4.6.16

**EDIT**

I still have not gotten this to work. I have try to add this to the Taskprint.tpl

```
<div class="crm-contact_image crm-contact_image-block">
  <a href="{$imageURL}" class='crm-image-popup'>
    <img src="{$imageURL}" height={$imageThumbHeight} width={$imageThumbWidth}>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Edit 2**

Thank you so much. `Print.tpl` was the correct file and i was able to figure out my problem with the image now i was looking in the right place. I had to add this code to the `summary.tpl` for it to load.

```
<div class="contactCardRight">
              {crmRegion name="contact-basic-info-right"}
              {if !empty($imageURL)}
                <div id="crm-contact-thumbnail">
                  {include file="CRM/Contact/Page/ContactImage.tpl"}
                </div>
              {/if}                
                </div>
              {/crmRegion}
            </div>
            <!-- end of right side -->
```

Thanks

Comment: I have tried many thing and i still can not get this to work. anyone have an idea how i can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're looking at the right template.  When I press Print Summary, that's not the template that loads.

You can check which template is in use by pressing "Ctrl-U" to View HTML Source, then searching for ".tpl".  When I do that, I see `templates/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Print.tpl` instead.

Above the `{literal}` tag, I added the `{debug}` tag and reloaded the page in my browser.  This brought up a Smarty debug window; I confirmed that `$imageURL` is indeed available to this template (otherwise we'd need to add it in the corresponding PHP file).

So hopefully this is enough info to get you where you need!  Update your question if not.